# .OBJ Mesh not importing correctly into Blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, import

I recieved a Sketch up file I'm trying to import into Blender. I watched aa tutorial that said using obj was the best, so I exported the scene as a obj and tried importing it into Blender.
This is what the scene looks like:
[image]

I export as is and when I import into Blender this happens:
[image]

Can anyone help me please? 
I'm attaching a link to the Sketchup file, my internet is slow so can't upload the obj.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjixcx3i9rz7gsq/Ackermans%20%20%28email%29.skp?dl=0